# How to access a file(png file) generated by a gem in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Hi I am writing a gem and a rails application that uses this gem.

The gem based on values passed, produces a image file.(i am writing it in gem's root directory )

In my rails application, I want to access that image-file. how can I do that.

What modifications I should make both in the gem and the rails-app to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to do with this file? You can simply open a file with File.open(file_path), doesn't matter much where exactly it is located, but depending on what you want to do and how your server is setup there may be permission issues. Anyway, a gems root directory isn't exactly the right place to store files.

Comment: Its an image. i want to display it in my web page of my rails application

Comment: In which case you do not even have to 'access' it from Raiuls code. You just need to store it in the public folder (or some subfolder of public like /images) and it will be available to the outside. So you just would have to modify this gem so it would store it in the right place.

Comment: As you are writing the gem, it would seem to be most obvious to give end user of the gem the choice of where to write the file. If the gem is stand-alone, that should be any path (passed in as a parameter before the image is written), and the Rails app will need to manage where it goes. If it is a Rails plugin, then it may be ok for the gem to ask Rails or the Rails config for the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems):

> ### 7 Adding Assets to Your Gems
>
> Assets can also come from external sources in the form of gems.
>
> A good example of this is the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) gem which comes with Rails as the standard JavaScript library gem. This gem contains an engine class which inherits from `Rails::Engine`.  By doing this, Rails is informed that the directory for this gem may contain assets and the `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` directories of this engine are added to the search path of Sprockets.

So basically, create `vendor/assets/your-image.jpg` then you want something like:

**lib/jquery/rails/engine.rb**

```
module Jquery
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    end
  end
end
```

In your views, use the asset helpers such as:

```
<%= image_tag 'your-image.jpg' %>
```