# how to export assets from ruby gem to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, assets

I am building a gem (see [here](https://github.com/damoiser/qr-bills) for full source code) and I am having issues exporting assets to Rails.

The tests I wrote in the gem work well, but when I install the gem on Rails some of the assets are missing, for example the images are not found, I got the following error on Rails:

```
# error I got when installed on Rails
unable to open image `app/assets/images/swiss_cross.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701
```

The Gem code raising the error is this one:

```
# Gem source code
# lib/qr-bills/qr-generator.rb
[...]
    swiss_cross = Image.read("app/assets/images/swiss_cross.png")[0]
[...]
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: You can also consider turning your gem into an engine as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701099/how-to-access-a-filepng-file-generated-by-a-gem-in-my-rails-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use full paths to your assets like it has been done [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/3e26e06d06912341c9258cdd235461d196732aee/lib/sidekiq/web.rb#L23-L27) and don't depend on the files being present on your current directory. In your case Rails' already has `app/*`.